# How to provide activity Context to general application module using Dagger > 2.1.0

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to provide Activity/Fragment Context to general module, which can be used throughout the application.

Sample of module, which depends on context. Toast can be invoked from AppContext, but in this sample lets pretend we need Activity context:

```
public class ToastController {

    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public ToastController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void showToast(@StringRes int res) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getText(res), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
    }
}
```

I created abstract Activity which extends every Activity I use in project and through this Activity i want to provide Context using its provider to all Activities.

```
public abstract class CoreAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                AndroidInjection.inject(this);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(getContentLayout());
                ButterKnife.bind(this);
            }

            protected abstract @LayoutRes int getContentLayout();

        }
```

so I created Activity and injected ToastCotroller. Context should be provided from abstract CoreAppActivity but it is not.

```
 public class MainTabActivity extends CoreAppActivity {

        @Inject
        ToastController toastController;

        @Override
        public int getContentLayout() {
            return R.layout.activity_main_tab;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
          }
    ...
    }
```

Here is my module Components and modules I used to provide dependencies.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        MainTabActivityModule.class, //Here I added all module dependencies
})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
}
```

MainTabActivityModule in this class I added Activities ant it is also the class where CoreAppActivity is added and also has module which exposes its context.

```
@Module
public abstract class MainTabActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainTabActivity contributeMainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = ContextCoreActivityModule.class)
    abstract CoreAppActivity contributeCoreAppActivity();
}
```

Module **ContextCoreActivityModule** binds CoreAppActivity with its context

```
@Module
public abstract class ContextCoreActivityModule {
    @Binds
    abstract Context provideContext(CoreAppActivity featureActivity);
}
```

However Dagger throws error by compilation.

```
Error:(33, 10) error: The same map key is bound more than once for java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.app.Activity>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.app.Activity>>>
@Binds @dagger.multibindings.IntoMap @dagger.android.ActivityKey(system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.activities.CoreAppActivity.class) dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.app.Activity> system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.di.modules.MainTabActivityModule_ContributeCoreAppActivity.bindAndroidInjectorFactory(system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.di.modules.MainTabActivityModule_ContributeCoreAppActivity.CoreAppActivitySubcomponent.Builder)
@Binds @dagger.multibindings.IntoMap @dagger.android.ActivityKey(system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.activities.CoreAppActivity.class) dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.app.Activity> system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.di.modules.CoreActivityModule.bindYourActivityInjectorFactory(system.malbac.sk.attandancesystem.di.components.CoreActivitySubComponent.Builder)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can have two `@ContributesAndroidInjector` statements in a single module. What happens if you move those two statements to separate modules?